# Show that P the set of all primes is closed in the Euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Theorem: Prove the set P of all prime numbers
is a closed set of R

I am using TOPOLOGY WITHOUT TEARS by Sydney Morris

My thoughts on it

It would suffice to show that R$\setminus$P
is opened

The set (n,n+1) is opened

So R$\setminus$P=$\bigcup_{n\in P}$(n,n+1) is
opened so P is closed..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have the right idea, not quite right on the execution. You don't have pieces of the form $(n, n+1)$ in general. Almost all primes are not distance one apart.. (Though a modest modification of what you have is almost there.) You're also missing the parts trailing off to negative and positive infinity.

Comment: They are primes of different type So R\P=(-inf,2n)$\cup$(2n,inf)$\cup$(-inf,2n+1)$\cup$(2n+1,inf) Then take the union of them all

Comment: I said your idea is right but you executed it wrong which means it's imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right. We can think of the complement of the set of prime numbers as a countable union of open intervals, so open.

Another way to see this is to use the sequence convergence characterization of closed sets. If $n_i$ is a sequence in $P$ with limit $n,$ then it could be checked (easily) that $n=n_i$ for some $i,$ so $n\in P$ also. Thus $P$ is closed since any limit of sequences in $P$ still belongs to $P.$